# Using two namespaces only works partly

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

When I try to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Direction
{
    enum Enum { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
}

using namespace std;

void move(int pDir);

int main()
{
    printf("UP: %u\n", Direction::UP);
    printf("DOWN: %u\n", Direction::DOWN);
    printf("LEFT: %u\n", Direction::LEFT);
    printf("RIGHT: %u\n", Direction::RIGHT);

    move(Direction::UP);

    return 0;
}

void move(int pDir)
{
    printf("Move: ");
    switch(pDir) 
    {
        case(Direction::UP):
            printf("UP");
            break;
        case(Direction::DOWN):
            printf("DOWN");
            break;
        case(Direction::RIGHT):
            printf("RIGHT");
            break;
        case(Direction::LEFT):
            printf("LEFT");
            break;
        default:
            printf("nothing");
            break;
    }
}
```

The result I expect would be:

```
UP: 0
DOWN: 1
LEFT: 2
RIGHT: 3
Move: UP
```

Instead the result is:

```
UP: 0
DOWN: 1
LEFT: 2
RIGHT: 3
```

It seems like `void move(..)` just gets ignored.

I already found the problem: It's the `using namespace std`. When I delete it, I get the result as expected.

So I have three questions:

1) Why does `void move(..)` just gets "ignored"

2) Why can I access the members of Direction within the first four lines of `int main()`

3) How can I fix this? ,_,

Have a nice day my friends.

ps: This is an extracted example of my problem, on my project I need to use the namespace std.

Comment: not sure if thats the problem here, but at least it is a source of confusion: dont use `using namespace std;`, there is also `std::move`, do you know which one it is when you write `move` ? ;)

Comment: just saw the "I need to use the namespace std" but tbh i cannot believe it. why do you **need** to do such a terrible thing?

Comment: @user463035818 That's the exact problem. (Well, plus the UB with the `printf`s)

Comment: Oh... Okay, I guess I'll stick to not use "using namespace std". In my projects I use a lot of functions like cout, cin, setw, etc. Still,  thanks for the fast answer.

I'll edit it to "using namespace::cout, cin, etc."

Comment: @user463035818 's comment is the answer; see this: https://www.ideone.com/bcRX3P And ::move(Direction::UP); will fix it.

Comment: its a matter of taste, but i would not even do that, once you are `using` `std::move` you again cannot easily spot the difference between `std::move` or `::move` (btw  `::move` might fix your problem, but I am not sure at all)

Comment: Or you can just _type_ `std::cout`. explicit > implicit. Those few characters aren't that hard to type. Eventually, if in a specific scope you use an identifier from `::std` a lot, you should `using std::identifier` to save some typing. But in general, just be explicit and help your future self ;)

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming no thats not an answer and I would not suggest to rename lots of stuff to avoid name clashes, the way to avoid name clashes is namespaces ;)

Comment: @user463035818 *there is also std::move, do you know which one it is when you write move ?* you mentioned this. My intention was to prove 
 it by giving another name(even-though it was clear to me)

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming yes and thats fine, its just that i am a bit nitpicky and wouldnt call that an answer for the reason i mentioned ;)

Comment: With `using namespace std;` you told the compiler that you don't care about the benefits of namespaces. But you do care, so don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your move function application has been reviewed and unfortunately, a
>   better application has been found. Please don't hesitate to reach us
>   for comments or questions.

[std::move in utility header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is the function being called in this situation. This is due to multiple factors :

- The *utility* header is included by *iostream*, so it is defined in your code
- Because of `using namespace std`, any function definition in the std namespace is [now candidate for overload resolution in the global scope (see Namespace scope)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).
- The argument `Direction::UP` is a rvalue, and the signature of std::move is `template< class T >constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;`. T can resolve to the enum type without conversion.
- Yours is `void move(int pDir);` and will require an ***implicit conversion*** from `Direction::Enum&&` to `int`

When you remove on of these condition your function will be called. For instance

```
move((int)Direction::UP);
```

remove the need for an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Due to your `using namespace std` both `move` (yours) and `std::move` are now accessible through the name `move` and when you call it, the usual overload resolution takes place, so the compiler checks whether

`move(int)`

or

`template<typename T> move(T) // bit simplified here`

is a better match for your call `move(Direction::UP)`. Since the underlying type (aka `std::underlying_type`) of an unscoped enum is implementation defined, it may be a `char` or `short` (or anything else), in which case the second candidate is a better match.

Other factors (like the rvalue-ness mentioned by UmNyobe) and the namespace of the arguments can as well have an influence on overload resolution. Moving the definition of your `move` into the `Direction` namespace for example should lead to the first candidate being called, since ADL (argument dependent lookup) kicks in, although I am not 100% sure on that right now.

So my advice, as already suggested by the others, is to avoid `using namespace` as much as possible, at least at file scope. If you need to access a lot of stuff from one namespace, simply put the `using namespace` into the function that requires it. Regarding namespace `std` in particular, I highly recommend to never use `using namespace std`.